# How to add a constraint that checks the sum in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently doing a school project in which we need to create a database for a real estate management company. We have an `OWNER` table, a `BUILDING` table, and an `OWNERSHIP` table.

I want to make sure that when I enter a value for the ownership stake percentage, the sum of all ownership stakes from the various owner doesn't exceed 100%. At the moment I have no idea how to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE Building (
    buildingID          NUMBER (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    qtyUnits            NUMBER (3) NOT NULL,
    landValue           NUMBER (15) NOT NULL,
    purchasePrice       NUMBER (15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Owners (
    ownerID          NUMBER (5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    lastName         VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    firstName        VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    telephone        VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    email            VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Ownership (
    ownerID             NUMBER (5) NOT NULL,
    buildingID          NUMBER (5) NOT NULL,
    ownershipStake      NUMBER (5,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Ownership PRIMARY KEY (ownerID,buildingID)
);
```

Comment: An aside - you'd do better using `snake_case` for Oracle tables and columns than `CamelCase`.

Comment: @DavidFaber - I'd never heard it called `snake_case` before. Is it still `SNAKE_CASE` when it's in uppercase?

Comment: @BobJarvis - no, then it's called COBOL_CASE :)

Comment: @APC: but...if I use COBOL_CASE identifiers...in an Oracle database...accessed by a C back-end...with a JavaScript front-end... That's odd...why do I hear a faint c̴h̷i͏tt̕erìn҉g̕..? NOOOOOOO!!!!!!!! IA!! IA!! CTHULHU!!!! CTHULHU FHTAGN!!!!!! :-}

Answer (score 5):

All trigger-related solutions share one problem: as soon as you have more than one user in the system, they are not enough to guarantee that the constraint is upheld. For example, if session A inserts `ownershipshare` of 51%, and session B inserts `ownershipshare` of 51%, both these inserts will succeed because neither session has committed. Then both sessions commit and you have a total ownershpshare of 102%.

One way you can get around this is with an `ON COMMIT` materialized view with a constraint. Unfortunately, I think materialized views are a feature available only in Oracle Enterprise Edition and not Standard or Express. I don't have an EE instance around to test with, but I think this does what you want:

```
create materialized view log on ownership
with primary key, rowid, sequence
( ownershipstake )
including new values;

create materialized view mv_ownership
refresh fast on commit
as
select buildingid, sum(ownershipstake) as total_ownershipstake, count(*) as count_ownershipstake
from ownership
group by buildingid;

alter materialized view mv_ownership add (
    constraint ck_100 check ( total_ownershipstake <= 100 )
);
```

I went to a little extra work to make the materialized view fast-refreshable, so the whole thing doesn't have to be rebuilt on each commit, just the affected buildingid's.

Comment: Actually a simple "for update" will take care of timing issue quite gracefully.  Materialized view is too heavy but interesting approach.   The materialized view is equal to a solution where we maintain a separate table via triggers.  If this was the only use of that table it may not be desirable.  But maybe having this as an object could be good to have in a real world lb d scenario

Comment: The materialised view is ok, but not portable. If you check out my answer - this avoids any concurrency problems, as the check is done by a table constraint.

Answer (score 1):

First of all -- you could use the front-end to manage that in a separate query (i.e. limit the maximum stake by the amount left).

Should you wish to do a database check -- creating a row-level trigger on the Ownership table can help.

**EDITED: adding more details**
So, maybe you have already discovered that the trigger will encounter "mutating table" and are wondering "what is this guy talking about?" 
OK, let me explain: this is not the complete answer to the problem.

My preferred way of dealing with this would be to use a combination of row-level AFTER trigger, an extra supplementary field in the table, and a check constraint.

1. Add an extra field to the `Ownership` table -- let's call it `owned_pct`
2. Add a check constraint on that field that says `owned_pct <= 100`
3. Create a row-level AFTER trigger that will update this value, e.g. for INSERT: `update Ownership set owned_pct= nvl(owned_pct,0)+:new.ownership_pct where building_id = :new.building_id;`
4. Note that there will be slightly different update queries for INSERT / DELETE / UPDATE cases, so make sure to test all of those

This process will try to update the `owned_pct` column and cause a constraint violation, which will roll back the transaction, including the initial DML statement.

Comment: A row-level trigger can't read data from the table on which it is defined.

Comment: Yes you can use row level triggers.  Trick is that in row level you add pk to a plsql array.  Then in "after statement" you need to go through that array and there it is allowed to query same table.  I hope that the perfectly good answer was not downvoted over this.  If so stackoverflow culture needs to evolve! Before downvoting at least know if you know answer yourself

Comment: That's a compound trigger, which fires once per row and once per statement.

Comment: @mathguy - but let me explain a little bit here: yes, JUST creating a row-level trigger will not work. There are, however, working solutions that WILL work, based on the row-level triggers. This is a little bit more complicated, but, given that the question is clearly on the "school project", I wouldn't like to expand to the full details.

In the interest of the community, thought, let me expand my answer

Comment: @SaadAhmad - and, yes, I do know the answer myself - you can use a compound trigger (but it's even more complicated than you describe). I prefer the materialized view approach, with refresh fast on commit. But either way, the whole thing is very much beyond the OP's level - "school project" suggests they are just beginning, and table-wide constraints are an advanced topic even for experts.

Comment: @Megadest - if you meant more, then you should say more. A future reader can't possibly guess what you meant, but didn't write. Other than that, we seem to agree that the project is unfair (too difficult).

Comment: @mathguy -- well, I do not agree that the project is too difficult if it calls for some non-obvious solutions :) After all, if everything asked is trivial -- then why ask? I'd expect some effort at least.

There are solutions, some of those are published and could be googled, others may be presented here ;)

Comment: @Megadest - "some non-obvious solutions" is not the same as "too difficult". I did mean what I said - unless this is a graduate-level course in Oracle SQL, the problem is unfairly difficult - emphasis not on "difficult" but on "unfairly".

Comment: @mathguy - then we don't seem to agree. There is a number of solutions to this problem, and even more if you put it in context (i.e. application logic). 
One could make a front-end check or procedural block to perform updates (with any logic you want in a full-blown pl/sql), in addition to the solutions already mentioned. 
But this seems to be off-topic -- the working solution has just been published anyway, and I am going to restrict my further comments to that :)

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***: Originally deleted this when I realized it was not sufficient when more than one session was involved. Undeleting to show an example of a solution that does not exhibit the "mutating table" problem. You'd have to lock the table so only one session could affect it at a time first.

You can do this with an `AFTER STATEMENT` trigger. That runs once per `insert`, `update`, or `delete`, after the entire statement is complete. That's a little sloppy, because it validates *all* the rows in the table, even ones that were not affected, but for your purposes is probably good enough.

```
create or replace trigger trig1 
after insert or update on ownership
declare
    l_count number;
begin
    select count(*) into l_count from (
      select buildingid, sum(ownershipstake)
        from ownership
      group by buildingid
      having sum(ownershipstake) > 100
    );

    if l_count > 0 then
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'Totals cant be over 100' );
    end if;
end;
/

insert into ownership values ( 1, 1, 99 );

insert into ownership values ( 2, 1, 2 );

Error starting at line : 24 in command -
insert into ownership values ( 2, 1, 2 )
Error report -
ORA-20001: Totals cant be over 100
```

As I said, this validates the *entire table* even though I only inserted a row that affected 1 building here. So if you had a million buildings, it validates 999,999 rows unnecessarily and can have a significant performance impact.

An improved way of doing this is a compound trigger, where at the `before each row` timing point, you would record the building id of the row being changed. Then, at the `after statement` timing point, you would validate only the buildingids that had been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use compound trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IVAN.trades_partial_kontrola_tg
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ivan.trades_partial
COMPOUND TRIGGER  

cNic CONSTANT NUMBER(10) := -9999999999;
--CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IVAN.NUMBER_POLE_TYP  as table of number;
lPole          ivan.number_pole_typ := ivan.number_pole_typ();
lPole2         ivan.number_pole_typ;
lAmountTrades  ivan.trades.amount%TYPE;
lAmountPartial ivan.trades_partial.amount%TYPE;

BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN updating
                 AND :new.amount = :old.amount THEN
            NULL;
        WHEN nvl(:new.amount, cNic) <> nvl(:old.amount, cNic) THEN
            lPole.extend();
            lPole(lPole.last()) := nvl(:new.id, :old.id);

    END CASE;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT column_value BULK COLLECT INTO lPole2 FROM TABLE(lPole);
    lPole.delete;

    FOR a_cur IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(lPole2))
    LOOP

        SELECT t.amount INTO lAmountTrades FROM ivan.trades t WHERE t.id = a_cur.column_value;
        SELECT SUM(a.amount) INTO lAmountPartial FROM ivan.trades_partial a WHERE a.id = a_cur.column_value;

        IF lAmountPartial <> lAmountTrades
        THEN
            ivan.log_centralni_pk.myraise('Wrong amount check');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END AFTER STATEMENT;
end;
```